# Angular 2 inject service into dynamic component

Tags: angular

I'm creating a multi-step user signup where after each step, the server returns the HTML string of the next form to complete. At each step, I set that HTML as the template of a Form Component that I dynamically created using a CompileService. This works fine and the form looks good, but I can't add any services to that dynamically created form, I keep getting issues like

`"Cannot resolve all parameters"`

Here is my CompileService

```
import { Component, ComponentMetadata, ComponentResolver, Injectable, ReflectiveInjector, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CompileService {
constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

createComponent(metadata: ComponentMetadata, vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        let cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};

        let decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(decoratedCmp).then(factory => {
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(providers, vcRef.parentInjector);
            vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
        });
    }
}
```

I wish to edit this service so that it not only creates components on-the-fly, but can also inject services into that component. How may I do this?

Comment: I have this problem too.. :(

Comment: I know this is coming kinda late, but you could try adding `@Inject(ComponentResolver)` before `private resolver: ComponentResolver` in your constructor. If you're not transpiling your code, the compiler doesn't know where to look for the `ComponentResolver` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Look in this line of code and please explain what **providers** parameter is...

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(providers, vcRef.parentInjector);
```

I can't tell what it is or where it comes from. In this case I would tell you...

> **"Cannot resolve all parameters"**